# How to group Expressions (Regex, c++)?

Tags: c++, regex, string, grouping

Now I've been using `regex` for quite a time, but there's one thing I just can't get right. This is frustrating, because the problem is fairly simple.

Look at this string:

```
std::string str{ "a/b/c/ /space/1235/@*#+/" };
```

Obviously it's structure is

`at-least-one-character` + `/` + `at-least-one-character`+ `/` ...

(in regex: `.+` + `/` + `.+` ...)

Anyway, I just can't get the expression right, that should fit this string.
This is what I first came up:

```
std::regex expression1{ "(.+/)+" };
```

But I noticed, that this is actually the same as `".+/"`, since `.+` covers everything until the last `'/'` ...

So I noticed I have to exclude the `/` in `.+` and now it looks like this:

```
std::regex expression2{ "((.^/)+/)+" };
```

Which is not working. So in the end, how can I group `(.^/)+` and `/` to a main expression `"(...)+"` ? Did I miss something elementary? Thank you for your help!

Comment: This `.^/` isn't the thing you think. But this is `[^/]` and the whole thing: `([^/]+/)+`

Comment: You won't retain repeated captures.  Use `[^/]+` and grab all matches.

Comment: Are you trying to capture each occurence of the words between `/`? Because else there is no distinction between `a/` and `a/b/` unless you need a certain number of "segments".

Comment: Try it with lazy matching: `(.+?\/)+?`

Comment: @revo: You may turn your comments into answer.

Comment: What do you want to capture?

Comment: @revo thank you, this actually helped me, looking back. Thanks alot. :) !